# Passing value to SQL query parameter from a textbox

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am using following code to connect to my database.

```vb
Dim conStr As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;    ![enter image description here][1]
       AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dbTest.mdf;
       Integrated Security=True;
       User Instance=True"

Dim sqlQry As String = "SELECT * FROM [tblTest] WHERE ([Name] = @Name)"
Dim dAdt As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlQry, conStr)
Dim dSet As New DataSet()
```

Then filling adapter with

```
dAdt.Fill(dSet, "tblTest")
```

and then I can use the data the way I want.

**My question is:** 
How to pass the value of parameter that user will give through a text box on my webform.

```
Dim sqlQry As String = "SELECT * FROM [tblTest] <b>WHERE ([Name] = @Name)
```

I mean how to pass the parameter value to my query?
Please modify my code to tell me how to do it.
Thanks a lot.
[image]

Comment: what did you try and what was your results ?

Comment: I could not try anything...... No hint where to begin

Comment: My friend it is easy to say for you.  But where I live there are no courses or books available.  I only have internet as source of learning

Comment: @Furqan I have given you many links to websites in previous questions which have the answers in them. Have you not read them?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add parameter object and put your code in Button's Click handler or any other event you want to use. (read @cjk post).

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim conStr As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\dbTest.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        Dim sqlQry As String = "SELECT * FROM [tblTest] WHERE ([Name] = @Name)"
        Dim Cn As New SqlConnection(conStr)
        Dim SelectCmd As New SqlCommand(sqlQry, Cn)
        SelectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text)
        'Or
        'SelectCmd.Parameters.Add("@Name",System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=value_here
        Dim dAdt As New SqlDataAdapter(SelectCmd)

        Dim dSet As New DataSet
        dAdt.Fill(dSet, "tblTest")
        ......
End Sub
```

Comment: It says declaration expected on SelectCmd, despite it has been declraed on the upper line  SelectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",value_here)

Comment: I have added my question showing the pic. with error.  Please check that. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Which ones? can you suggest how?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3306/discussion-between-furqan-sehgal-and-adatapost)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put you non-declarative (i.e. code that does stuff) into a method.

The lines at the top of your example, under the class declaration are just declarations of variables, and are set up when the class is instatiated.

For it to actually do something, there needs to be a method that is called.

Comment: No, you need to learn how basic program structures work first.